# Package name does not correspond to the file path - Gradle configuration

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying migrating a normal Android Studio (IntelliJ) project to Gradle project recently.  And currently I'm encounter a problem: IntelliJ gives me a warning on the beginning of every file says that my *'package name does not correspond to the file path'*. e.g.

The first line of my some/prefixes/a/b/c/d/E.java is:

```
package a.b.c.d;
....
```

IntelliJ thinks the package name should be '**c.d**' instead of '**a.b.c.d**'. Because I set

```
SourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ["some/prefixes/a/b"] 
}
```

in the module's build.gradle.

I know I could do the change below to make IntelliJ happy:

```
SourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['some/prefixes'] 
}
```

But I can't do that because there're huge numbers of projects under '`some/prefixes`' and I definitely don't want to introduce all of them into this module.

I used to add a **packagePrefix="a.b"** in my '`module.iml`' in my original Android studio project and it works well:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html#d2814695e312

But I don't know how to accomplish similar fix after migrating to Gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

I end up to write a task for *gradle*.
The task add the famous **packagePrefix** to the *.iml file.

This solution only work for *intelliJ*, I hope someone have a better solution.

```
task addPackagePrefix << {
println 'addPackagePrefix'
def  imlFile = file(MODULE_NAME+".iml")

if (!imlFile.exists()) {
    println 'no module find '
    return

}
def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(imlFile)

if(parsedXml.component[1] && parsedXml.component[1].content){
    parsedXml.component[1].content.findAll { Node node ->
        node.sourceFolder.findAll { Node s ->
            def url = s.attribute("url").toString()

            if (url.endsWith(SRC_DIR)) {
                println 'Node founded '
                def attr = s.attribute('packagePrefix')
                if (attr == null) {
                    // add prefix
                    println 'Adding package prefix'
                    s.attributes().put('packagePrefix', PACKAGE_NAME)
                    println s.toString()

                    // writing
                    def writer = new StringWriter()
                    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(parsedXml)
                    imlFile.text = writer.toString()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```